# Best XMPP Client PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xmpp

Which one is the best XMPP client library for PHP/javascript?
I have gone through many of these like:

JSJaC
XMPPHP
MISSUS
Kaazing Gateway

Some one having experience in using these will have better idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems [jaxl](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2010/01/jaxl-bosh-demo-im-chat-client-for-all-wordpress-blogs/) support [bosh](http://metajack.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/xmpp-is-better-with-bosh/). Then I would look into [strophe.js](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/). I myself don't have hands on experience, but if I would implement this in PHP I would try to do it like this.

Answer (score 4):

[hxmpp](https://github.com/tong/hxmpp/) is written in Haxe and supports JavaScript *and* PHP. so you can use (a part) of your code on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

[Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) is the best with full basic protocol of XMPP, detail documentation and wide community that can support you in the beginning.