# Is there a way to send a message over Google Talk using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-talk

I have an HTML5/JS app that will be running on in-dash vehicle display units.  The problem I have is that when I test the app on the actual hardware, I have no access to the javascript console.

To get around this I started creating a simple remote logging server in PHP.  This way I can just modify the logging function in my app to post to this site and be able to access the logs through a browser.

But then I stopped and wondered if there might be an even simpler solution...Google Talk!?

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a simple way to send a message over Google Talk using only javascript?  This would be more than sufficient for what I need, and would be awesome to just be able and watch the logs come in straight to my phone.

I did find this page:
https://developers.google.com/talk/talk_developers_home

But, it seems a little complex and only mentions Java and Python.  All I need is one-way text-only communication.  Really I'm hoping that there is some API I can just direct an HTTP request to.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Gtalk follows XMPP standard so any XMPP JS client will be enough for you.

[Heres](http://zakhomuth.com/in-browser-pure-javascript-xmpp-client) one

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495154/best-xmpp-client-php-javascript) is SO question on which one is best.

Comment: Seems like overkill, I don't want to include a bunch of third party code into my app just to accomplish some temporary logging.  Any way to just make a jQuery.ajax call to send a message to someone one-way??

Answer (score 0):

Does your embedded app run on Opera? If so... http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/remote/

Comment: Negative, running on Chromium I believe