# Creating chat application on XMPP using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, xmpp

I am trying to create a web chat application with PHP, MySQL.
I want to stream the data from the server to client instead of requesting the server in a regular intervals which will cause huge load at servers.
I believe this is possible in many ways and XMPP is one of those i heard earlier, but i have no idea how to adopt this xmpp into scripts, how to use it?
If some one can give some examples or code references that would be great help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495154/best-xmpp-client-php-javascript take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the documentation of XMPP,
All the social media sites including Google facebook uses XMPP in their instant messaging.

Answer (score 0):

For working with XMPP on client side, you can either use websockets or http bind(aka bosh) based on your requirements and support from the xmpp server. I have tried and experimented with [trophyjs](https://code.google.com/p/trophyim/) and [Candy.Js](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/). Candy being slightly better in terms of plugins and support if you like chat rooms.